# Using Step Function Optimised Integration to access a DynamoDB table in another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

We have an AWS Step Function which uses the [DynamoDB Optimised Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html) to update items within a DynamoDB table.  Both of these are deployed to the same region, Region A, and work perfectively well.

We would like to deploy the Step Function to another region B.  This is effectively the same Step Function, and the intention is that it will access the original DynamoDB table that is still in Region A.

However, looking at the documentation on the DynamoDB Optimised Integration, I don't see a way in which I can specify the region of the table I want the Step Function to access.  It seems to assume that the table is in the same region as the Step Function.

Is there a way for the Step Function to use the DynamoDB Optimised Integration to access a DynamoDB table in a different region?

Note: I'm aware that Global Tables and Lambdas would work here.  But I'd like to know if this is possible before considering these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a Dynamo table in another region using the integration, it assumes the region endpoint and doesn't have any option to set the endpoint like the SDK does.

Comment: Is there any reference documentation stating that this is the case?  I get the sense that this is true but anything that could confirm it would be great.

Comment: There's nothing spelled out in the integration docs you linked, but there's also no clearly defined parameter to choose a region or specify an alternative DynamoDB API endpoint. However, and again, nothing's spelled out, but you might be able to enter the region-specific ARN for the table in the "Resource" field, but I highly doubt that it'll work cross-region like that. You're better off converting the table to global, which should be accessible by the step function regardless of which region it's in. As opposed to also making the lambdas global.

Comment: I got confirmation from someone working at AWS that this answer is indeed correct.